# How to handle Keystores / Deployment with docker

Tags: docker, deployment, keystore, ballerina

I'm trying to use Ballerina to build a REST-Api that uses JWT Authentication and is deployed with docker.

I managed building a simple service with a few endpoints and deploying a Docker image.

Now I want to add JWT authentication.

I tried using this example: https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/secured-service-with-jwt-auth.html
(v1.2 and Swan Lake)

However, when I try to run the example i get:
"error: KeyStore File \bre\security\ballerinaKeystore.p12 not found" (I'm using Windows)
(I probably have to set my own keystore here for it to work, but the example does no say anything about that.)

EDIT: Nevermind... I'm an idiot. Forgot to pass --b7a.home=
But that still leaves my following questions regarding deployment with docker.

Also: (I think) I understand what a keystore is and why I need it. but: How do I handle keystores during development or when deploying? Seems like a bad idea to push the keystore file to a repo. Where do I save it? and how do I deploy it? Or did I get something completely wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You could refer to [Sample with Docker](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/module-ballerina-docker/tree/master/samples/sample7), [Sample with Kubernetes](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/module-ballerina-kubernetes/tree/master/samples/sample4) on how to deploy https services using the Annotations.

To use without annotations, you will need to copy the keystores/trustores to the docker file and give that path to the configurations of the http service's listener. In production you will most probably have your own keystores and truststores. So it is always better to copy these to the docker file and make your services run.